# Program the Navigation Pane in Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find a way to program the new Navigation pane in Word 2010 to change tabs when a user selects a picture in the document. I can capture the selection change with `WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)`, but I can't figure out how change the tab from "Browse the headings" to "Browse the pages", which is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using iAccessible!

```
Dim As IAccessible

Set oIA = CommandBars("Navigation")

oIA.Visible = True
```

Then deep recursively find a child with `accName="Navigation"` and `accRole=38`

then its child with index 3 has `accValue=NAVBAR` and `accRole=60`

Then the child 2 of NAVBAR is what you need.

```
 .accDoDefaultAction CHILDID_SELF
```

Comment: I tried doing this in C# but the CommandBar only has two children, neither of which has any children of their own.

Comment: @Chris. I wonder if you are looking at the right kind of children? FWIW With Word 2010 using the VBA downloadable from http://www.wordarticles.com/Shorts/RibbonVBA/RibbonVBADemo.php and the following code - you will need to unravel it a bit - I was able to switch tabs, but (a) I haven't looked at what is going on in depth so cannot yet debug and (b) cannot translate to C#:
Set oIA = CommandBars("Navigation"):
oIA.Visible = True:
GetListOfChildren(GetListOfChildren(GetAccessible(oIA, 38, "Navigation", False), False).Objects(2), False).Objects(2).accDoDefaultAction CHILDID_SELF

Comment: As far as I can tell, my code is doing the same thing. I have to abandon this for now; if I revisit it, I'll ask a new question and link to this one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MVP on this [thread](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeprog/thread/650e744a-ed4d-4231-b72b-0af7532dd16a), it's not programmable/searchable.