# Navigation Pane Word 2013

Tags: navigation, pane

How do I disable the Navigation Pane in Word 2013 using a Registry Key?
I am trying to alter the Registry Key so that the Navigation Pane is always disabled when starting Word.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401948/program-the-navigation-pane-in-word-2010), you can do it in code. Here's how I enabled it in a document-level add-in:

```
Globals.ThisDocument.Application.CommandBars["Navigation"].Visible = true;
```

You'd want false, of course, not true.