# Navigation Pane automation macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to figure out a way to automate the navigation pane so that when you open a document, it automatically searches and shows results for all of the word comments in that document. The manual way to do this is to click the drop down arrow next to the navigation search bar, select comments under find and then select all reviewers. Is there a way to automate this?

Thanks!

Code below:
* The code works as it should but it does not actually display any comments. If you do this process manually, it will display all the comments in the document. If I use this macro, it will say no results found, even if the search bar has the same info. I've tried defining a range as the entire document but it hasn't worked.

```
Sub AutoOpen()

' Activate/Deactivate Navigation Pane
' Collapse All, to only show heading level 1
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
  ActiveWindow.DocumentMap = True

  If ActiveWindow.DocumentMap = True Then

'  Ctrl-F = Find --> this sets the cursor at the top of the navigation pane
'  ^ = Ctrl key
'  + = Shift key
 SendKeys "^(f){TAB}{ENTER}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}
{ENTER}{DOWN}{ENTER}"

End If
ActiveWindow.View.ShowComments = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far? Any implementation?

Comment: Dont place code as a comment please. The site allows for code formatting if you put it into your question. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: Anyone? Would this be able to be done through UI customization instead?

Comment: I don't think there is an option to automate it. You can create custom user form and launch that form while opening the document and list and navigate comment option in that user form can be provided. This is one of the simple option in vba.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is an exact answer to your question, but your attempt helped me find a creative way of using the new Word2016 navigation pane. I designed a userFrom to select special characters to be searched. In my case, to have navigation pane to display items, I had to dismiss the form and perform an ActiveDocuemnt.activate. Then and only then the navigation pane showed its results. Thanks.

```
  DoEvents
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ' put text in word, copy to clipboard, and undo it
  Dim s As Long
  Dim e As Long
  s = Selection.start
  Selection.TypeText "the text I want to search that comes from my userform"
  e = Selection.start
  Selection.SetRange start:=s, End:=e
  Selection.Copy
  ActiveDocument.Undo
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  ' make document map active
  ActiveWindow.DocumentMap = True
  ' fortunately input field has focus, erase any content, paste
  SendKeys "^(f){backspace}^{v}{Enter}"
  Me.hide ' I hide my user form
  ActiveDocument.Activate ' i activate the active document to see the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with legacy MSAA's IAccessible interface (not Microsoft UI Automation)

I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300824/2981328)

I found the path in the hierarchy with AccExplorer 2.0.

Now, one can even add fields with buttons than can update based on a document property, but also are double clickable to trigger the following macro which will highlight them all in a nice modern UI color: `{ MACROBUTTON ModernHighlightAllFields { DOCPROPERTY _COMPANY  \* MERGEFORMAT}}`

```
Sub ModernHighlightAllFields()

'ActiveWindow.DocumentMap = True --> Headings

ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True

Const NAVDIR_MIN = 0&
Const NAVDIR_UP = 1&
Const NAVDIR_DOWN = 2&
Const NAVDIR_LEFT = 3&
Const NAVDIR_RIGHT = 4&
Const NAVDIR_NEXT = 5&
Const NAVDIR_PREVIOUS = 6&
Const NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD = 7&
Const NAVDIR_LASTCHILD = 8&
Const NAVDIR_MAX = 9&

Const SELFLAG_NONE = 0&
Const SELFLAG_TAKEFOCUS = 1&
Const SELFLAG_TAKESELECTION = 2&
Const SELFLAG_EXTENDSELECTION = 4&
Const SELFLAG_ADDSELECTION = 8&
Const SELFLAG_REMOVESELECTION = 10&

Const CHILDID_SELF = 0&

Dim accObj As IAccessible, i As Long, j As Long, lChildCount As Long
Dim accObjSearchDoc As IAccessible

Set accObj = CommandBars("Navigation") 'NAMELESS[tool bar - Visible]
accObj.Visible = True
DoEvents

Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'Navigation[window - Visible]
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'Navigation[client - Visible]
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'NAMELESS[window - Visible]
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'NAMELESS[client - Visible]
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'Navigation[window - Visible]
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'Navigation[property page - Visible]

Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'Search document[editable text - Visible]
Set accObjSearch = accObj

Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_NEXT, CHILDID_SELF) 'Search[grouping - Visible]
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_NEXT, CHILDID_SELF) 'NAMELESS[text - Visible]
Set accObjResults = accObj

Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_NEXT, CHILDID_SELF) 'Previous Result[push button - Visible]
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_NEXT, CHILDID_SELF) 'Next Result[pane - Visible]
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_NEXT, CHILDID_SELF) 'NAMELESS[pane - Visible]

Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'NAMELESS[page tab list - Visible]

Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_FIRSTCHILD, CHILDID_SELF) 'Headings
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_NEXT, CHILDID_SELF) 'Pages
Set accObj = accObj.accNavigate(NAVDIR_NEXT, CHILDID_SELF) 'Results

accObj.accDoDefaultAction CHILDID_SELF
accObjSearch.accSelect SELFLAG_TAKEFOCUS, CHILDID_SELF

DoEvents

VBA.Interaction.SendKeys "{^}d", True

Do
    DoEvents
    'wait for either case:
    '"No matches"
    '"100 results"
    '"Result 1 of 101"
Loop Until accObjResults.accName(CHILDID_SELF) <> ""

ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False

End Sub
```