# Word Vsto determine if Navigation Pane is visible

Tags: c#, plugins, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I'm developing a Word Vsto 2013+ with C# and I'm using Ribbon xml. Now I want to get the state of a built-in checkbox. The idMso is `NavigationPaneShowHide` and it is located in the `GroupViewShowHide` groupbox in the `TabView` tab.

I tried to 'overwrite' the `onAction` callback of the checkbox, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the visibility of the navigation pane like this:

```
CommandBar navPane = app.CommandBars["Navigation"];
// check navPane.Visible;
```

I don't believe there is a way to look at a built-in ribbon checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to check if the navigation pane is focused? So if the cursor is in the text box of it? And is there a way to get if the Find and Replace window is open? I mean the window that opens when you click on replace

Comment: I was looking into manipulating the contents of the navigation pane (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401948/program-the-navigation-pane-in-word-2010/32300824) but gave up on it due to difficulty and time constraints. Don't have an answer for the find/replace window but something similar might exist under a different key. Debug it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe I will try it. But your answer helped me very much